# error: incompatible type for argument in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have to input min and max value of array by using function minmax(double *x,double *y). 
When I compile it, there are some strange errors: incompatible type for argument 1 of minmax;  incompatible type for argument 2 of minmax. But idk where is a mistake. pls explain

The problem is to input max and min of array inputed from a file. I fulled file with some values.
and then sorted them from min to max.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void input (int *psize, double arr[]);
void output (int size, double arr[]);
void minmax (double *x, double *y);
int sorting(int size, double arr[]);

int main(){
    double arr[100];
    int size,i;
    input(&size,arr);
    output(size, arr);
    printf("\n");

    sorting(size, arr);
    output(size, arr);

    minmax(arr[0],arr[size-1]);

}

void input (int *psize, double arr[]){
    FILE *array;
    array = fopen("12_3.txt", "r");
    int t_size=0; 
    if (array == NULL){
        printf("CANNOT OPEN FILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (array!=NULL)
    {
        while( !feof(array))
            {
            fscanf(array, "%lf", &arr[t_size]); 
            t_size++;
            }
        *psize=t_size-1;
        fclose(array);

    }
}

void output (int size, double arr[]){
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            printf("%f \n",arr[i]);
        }
}

void minmax (double*x, double*y){
    printf("\nmax:  %f\n", *x);
    printf("min:  %f\n", *y);
}

int sorting(int size, double arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: So look at what the function expects and what you pass? It wants pointers. Is this a pointer? `arr[0]`

Comment: @Jul_kr To find minimum and maximum elements of an array there is no need to sort the array.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of `minmax()` - `y` and `x` - are of type pointer to `double` (`double *`).

The arguments of `arr[0]` and `arr[size-1]` at the call to `minmax()` are of type `double`.

There is a mismatch. Pointer to `double` vs. `double`.

---

Omit the `*` operator for `x` and `y` at the definition/declaration of `minmax()`:

```
void minmax (double x, double y) { ...
```

as well as as arguments at the calls to `printf()`:

```
printf("\nmax:  %f\n", x);
printf("min:  %f\n", y);
```

---

Result:

```
void minmax (double x, double y);      // Function prototype.

....

void minmax (double x, double y) {     // Function definition.
    printf("\nmax:  %f\n", x);
    printf("min:  %f\n", y);
}
```

Comment: @Jul_kr, if it works, you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852).